# Custom class for "woocommerce-info"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a special message to the cart with free shipping, but it has the same styles as the others. Is it possible to add an extra class for this post?

The code I used and the screenshot attached
[image]

```
add_action( 'wfc_before_cart', 'truemisha_free_shipping_notice' );

function truemisha_free_shipping_notice() {
 
    $min_amount = 1000; // укажите здесь минимальную сумму для бесплатной доставки
 
    $current = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
 
    if ( $current < $min_amount ) { // если в корзине меньше, чем надо
 
        wc_print_notice(
            sprintf(
                'Замовте ще на ' . wc_price( $min_amount - $current ) . ' для безкоштовної доставки!'
            ),
            'notice'
        );
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: You can create your own template file for the notice and add your classnames.  See the comment block at the top of the base notice template file: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/notices/notice.php

Answer (score 0):

`wc_print_notice()` function have optional parameter `$data`. So you can just put there some key => value

```
wc_print_notice(
            sprintf('Teext'),
            'notice',
            array('id' => 'your-custom-id')
        );
```

and it will end up in HTML as:

```
<div class="woocommerce-info" data-id="your-custom-id">
        <?php echo wc_kses_notice( $notice['notice'] ); ?>
</div>
```

Now if it has `data-id`, you can add your styles to CSS with `[data-id="your-custom-id"]` selector.